# Proving $\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{4x^2}{(x^4+2x^2+2)^2}dx\stackrel?=\frac{\pi}{4}\sqrt{5\sqrt2-7}$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, closed-form

$$\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{4x^2}{(x^4+2x^2+2)^2}dx=\frac{\pi}{15}$$

$$\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{4x^2}{[(1+(1+x^2)^2]^2}dx=\frac{\pi}{15}$$

$u=\tan(z)$ $\rightarrow$ $du=\sec^2(z)$

$u$ $\rightarrow \infty$, $\tan(z)=\frac{\pi}{2}$

$u$ $\rightarrow 0$, $\tan(z)=0$

$$\int_{0}^{\pi \over 2}\frac{4\tan^2(z)}{[(1+(1+\tan^2(z))^2]^2}\frac{du}{\sec^2(z)}=\frac{\pi}{15}$$

$1+\tan^2(z)=\sec^2(z)$

$$\int_{0}^{\pi \over 2}\frac{4\sin^2(z)}{[(1+\sec^4(z)]^2}dx=\frac{\pi}{15}$$

$$\int_{0}^{\pi \over 2}\frac{4\sin^2(z)}{[(1+i\sec^2(z))(1-i\sec^2(z))]^2}dx=\frac{\pi}{15}$$

Hopeless! Any suggestion?

Try again 
$$\int_{0}^{\pi \over 2}\frac{4\sin^2(z)}{[(1+\sec^4(z)]^2}dx=\frac{\pi}{15}$$

$$\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\sin^2(2z)\cos^6(z)}{(1+\cos^4(z))^2}dx=\frac{\pi}{15}$$

$\sin^2(2z)=\frac{1-\cos(4z)}{2}$

No more I gave up. Any hints?

Comment: Are you familiar with the residue theorem?

Comment: Alternatively, you could factor the denominator and do a partial fraction expansion.

Comment: @joriki no, I have no idea about residue theorem

Comment: Are you interested in a solution using the residue theorem?

Comment: @M10687 that be very long. Any shorter method?

Comment: Sure @joriki I want to see it. I want to see full steps no summaries steps

Comment: If you aren't interested in that then residue theorem is probably your best bet but that may be pretty lengthy too.

Comment: The problem with the residue theorem is that the asker must know some basic complex analysis. It is by far the fastest method, in my opinion, as partial fractions seems to be a nightmare here.

Comment: @Joanpemo is this something to do with complex numbers. I did Laplace transform before and remember something about complex number involving in it.

Comment: @Chinacat It's not only about "complex numbers" but about complex *analysis*: analytic complex functions, power series, Laurent series, poles (simple, double, essential...), complex integration, differentiation, etc.

Comment: That is close to $\frac{\pi}{15}$, but the value of the integral *is not* $\frac{\pi}{15}$, so I suggest to modify the question title.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Hint.** One may write
$$
\begin{align}
\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{4x^2}{(x^4+2x^2+2)^2}dx&=4\int_0^{\infty}\frac1{\left(\left(x-\frac{\sqrt{2}}x\right)^2+2+2\sqrt{2}\right)^2}\:\frac{dx}{x^2}
\\\\&=2\sqrt{2}\int_0^{\infty}\frac1{\left(\left(x-\frac{\sqrt{2}}x\right)^2+2+2\sqrt{2}\right)^2}\:dx \quad (x \to \sqrt{2}/x)
\\\\&=\frac1{\sqrt{2}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\left(1+\frac{\sqrt{2}}{x^2}\right)}{\left(\left(x-\frac{\sqrt{2}}x\right)^2+2+2\sqrt{2}\right)^2}\:dx
\\\\&=\frac1{\sqrt{2}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{d\left(x-\frac{\sqrt{2}}x\right)}{\left(\left(x-\frac{\sqrt{2}}x\right)^2+2+2\sqrt{2}\right)^2}
\\\\&=\frac1{\sqrt{2}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{du}{(u^2+2+2\sqrt{2})^2}
\\\\&=\color{red}{\frac14 \sqrt{5\sqrt{2}-7} \:\pi}
\\\\
\end{align}
$$

where we have made $u:=\sqrt{2+2\sqrt{2}}\:\sinh v$ to get the last step.

Comment: (+1) I agree with your computation, $\frac{\pi}{15}$ *is not* the actual value of the integral.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Thank you.

Comment: First of all @OlivierOloa thank for the correct answer. I admired your first step of transformation, which I understand clearly as to what follow i am quite lose. If you can provide me more detail. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Here  is an  approach  using  contour integration  in  case anyone  is
interested.  An  effort  has  been  made  to  use  pen-and-paper  type
manipulations only.  These are simple  yet demand a certain  care with
the algebra. Suppose we seek to verify that

$$\int_0^\infty \frac{4x^2}{(x^4+2x^2+2)^2} dx = 
\frac{\pi}{4} \sqrt{5\sqrt{2}-7}$$

or alternatively

$$\int_0^\infty \frac{x^2}{(x^4+2x^2+2)^2} dx = 
\frac{\pi}{16} \sqrt{5\sqrt{2}-7}.$$

We  use  a semicircular  contour  in the  upper  half  plane with  two
straight  components $\Gamma_0$  and  $\Gamma_1$ on  the positive  and
negative real axis and having radius $R$ ($\Gamma_2.$)

The denominator here is
$$((x^2+1)^2+1)^2$$
so the poles are double and located at

$$\rho_{0,1,2,3} = \pm\sqrt{-1\pm i}.$$

We convert this to polar form in order to determine which poles are in
the upper half plane, getting

$$\pm\sqrt{\sqrt{2} \exp(\pi i \pm \pi i/4)}
= \sqrt[4]{2} \exp(\pi i/2 \pm \pi i/8 + \pi i/2 \pm \pi i/2) 
\\ = \sqrt[4]{2} \exp(\pi i \pm \pi i/8 \pm \pi i/2).$$

Fortunately we can see by inspection that only the
two poles 
$$\rho_0 = \sqrt[4]{2} \exp(\pi i - \pi i/8 - \pi i/2)
= \sqrt[4]{2} \exp(3\pi i/8)
\\ \quad\text{and}\quad
\rho_1 = \sqrt[4]{2} \exp(\pi i + \pi i/8 - \pi i/2)
= \sqrt[4]{2} \exp(5\pi i/8)$$

are inside the contour (arguments are $3\pi/8$ and $5\pi/8$, the other
two are at $-3\pi /8$ and $-5\pi /8.$)

For the residue we get

$$\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z-\rho_0|=\epsilon} \frac{z^2}{(z^4+2z^2+2)^2} \; dz.$$

In order to  get a pole that is amenable to  easy algebra we introduce
$w = z\exp(-3\pi i/8)/\sqrt[4]{2}$ and 
$z = w\exp(3\pi i/8)\sqrt[4]{2}$
which maps $\rho_0$ to $1$ so we obtain

$$\exp(3\pi i/4+3\pi i/8)\sqrt{2}\sqrt[4]{2}
\\ \times  \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w\exp(3\pi i/8)\sqrt[4]{2}-1|=\epsilon} 
\frac{w^2}{(-2iw^4+2w^2(-1+i)+2)^2} \; dw
\\ = - \exp(9\pi i/8) \frac{2^{3/4}}{4} \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w-1|=\gamma} 
\frac{w^2}{(w-1)^2\times (w^2-i)^2(w+1)^2} \; dw.$$

The residue is thus given by

$$- \exp(9\pi i/8) \frac{2^{3/4}}{4} \lim_{w\rightarrow 1}
\left(\frac{w^2}{(w^2-i)^2(w+1)^2}\right)'
\\ = - \exp(9\pi i/8) \frac{2^{3/4}}{4} \lim_{w\rightarrow 1}
\left(\frac{2w}{(w^2-i)^2(w+1)^2}
\\ - \frac{w^2}{(w^2-i)^4(w+1)^4}
(2(w^2-i) 2w (w+1)^2 + (w^2-i)^2 2(w+1))\right).$$

This works out to
$$-\exp(9\pi i/8) \frac{2^{3/4}}{4} \times 
\frac{1}{8} (2-i)
= i\exp(-3\pi i/8) \frac{2^{3/4}}{4} \times 
\frac{1}{8} \sqrt{5} \exp(-i\beta)$$

where $2-i = \sqrt{5}\exp(-i\beta).$

Continuing with the second pole we we introduce
$w = z\exp(-5\pi i/8)/\sqrt[4]{2}$ and 
$z = w\exp(5\pi i/8)\sqrt[4]{2}$

and obtain

$$\exp(5\pi i/4+5\pi i/8)\sqrt{2}\sqrt[4]{2}
\\ \times  \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w\exp(5\pi i/8)\sqrt[4]{2}-1|=\epsilon} 
\frac{w^2}{(2iw^4+2w^2(-1-i)+2)^2} \; dw
\\ = - \exp(15\pi i/8) \frac{2^{3/4}}{4} \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w-1|=\gamma} 
\frac{w^2}{(w-1)^2\times (w^2+i)^2(w+1)^2} \; dw.$$

This  is the  same as  in the  previous pole  except the  sign  in the
$w^2-i$ term has been flipped. Re-using the derivative thus yields

$$-\exp(15\pi i/8) \frac{2^{3/4}}{4} \times 
\frac{1}{8} (2+i)
= i\exp(3\pi i/8) \frac{2^{3/4}}{4} \times 
\frac{1}{8} \sqrt{5} \exp(i\beta).$$

Adding the two residues we thus obtain

$$\frac{2^{3/4}}{32}\times\sqrt{5}\times 2i\cos(\beta+3\pi /8).$$

Returning to the main computation, on  the part of the contour that is
on the negative real axis which is $\Gamma_1$ we trivially obtain

$$\int_{-R}^0 \frac{x^2}{(x^4+2x^2+2)^2} \; dx$$

which yields with $z=-x$

$$- \int_R^0 
\frac{z^2}{(z^4+2z^2+2)^2} \; dz
= \int_{\Gamma_0} \frac{z^2}{(z^4+2z^2+2)^2} \; dz.$$

Finally we have by the ML bound for the semicircular component

$$\lim_{R\rightarrow\infty} 
\left|\int_{\Gamma_2} \frac{z^2}{(z^4+2z^2+2)^2} \; dz\right|
\le \lim_{R\rightarrow\infty} 2\pi R/2 \times 
\frac{R^2}{(R^4-2R^2+2)^2} = 0.$$

It follows that

$$\int_0^\infty \frac{x^2}{(x^4+2x^2+2)^2} \; dx
= \frac{1}{2}\times 2\pi i \times 
\frac{2^{3/4}}{32}\times\sqrt{5}\times 2i\cos(\beta+3\pi /8)
\\ = -\frac{\pi}{16} 2^{3/4} \sqrt{5} \cos(\beta+3\pi /8).$$

To  manipulate this  to  match the  form  in the  introduction we  use
angle sum and half-angle formulae as in

$$\sqrt{5}\cos(\beta+3\pi /8) =
\sqrt{5}\cos\beta\cos(3\pi /8) - \sqrt{5}\sin\beta\sin(3\pi /8)
\\ = 2\cos(3\pi /8) - \sin(3\pi /8).$$

As  we  are integrating  a  function that  is  never  negative on  the
integration interval  we see that the  sign on this last  term must be
negative. Observe that

$$\cos(3\pi/8) = \sqrt{\frac{1+\cos(3\pi/4)}{2}}
= \sqrt{\frac{1-\sqrt{2}/2}{2}}$$

and 
$$\sin(3\pi/8) = \sqrt{\frac{1-\cos(3\pi/4)}{2}}
= \sqrt{\frac{1+\sqrt{2}/2}{2}}.$$

Squaring we obtain

$$4 \frac{1-\sqrt{2}/2}{2} + \frac{1+\sqrt{2}/2}{2}
- 4 \sqrt{\frac{1-2/4}{4}}
= \frac{5}{2} - \frac{3}{4}\sqrt{2}-\sqrt{2}
\\ = \frac{5}{2} - \frac{7}{4}\sqrt{2}.$$

We thus have for the end result

$$-\frac{\pi}{16} 2^{3/4} \times
- \sqrt{\frac{5}{2} - \frac{7}{4}\sqrt{2}}
= \frac{\pi}{16} \times
\sqrt{\frac{5}{2}2^{3/2} - \frac{7}{4}2^2}
\\ = \frac{\pi}{16} \times \sqrt{5\sqrt{2}-7}.$$

This is the claim.

Comment: (+1)Marko Riedel. This is passed my pay grade. Is this a bachelor or a master level of maths?

Comment: Thank you for the upvote, my solution using complex variables is admittedly somewhat more involved than the other approaches. I would say it is about the level of a junior / senior introductory course in complex variables.